# Boot from USB with 3g/4g

Tags: usb, live-usb, hardware, 3g, 4g

Does a small USB stick exist which has built in 3g or 4g, and can be plugged into any computers usb port to boot into linux giving you internet access using the 3g or 4g built into the USB stick which booted linux?

Comment: why you ask yes or no type questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a small USB stick exist which has built in 3g or 4g, and can be plugged into any computers usb port to boot into linux giving you internet access using the 3g or 4g built into the USB stick which booted linux?

I am somewhat confused by the fact that this question is so short and still has a bounty on it. The short answer is; yes. There are 3G/4G modems that plug in via USB that also has storage on them, both internally and as an add-on (for example, some modems support inserting an SD card).

So is that the only thing you want answered? I think you need to elaborate what you want to get out of this question.

Here are a couple of examples:

- http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/3g-usb-modem-sd-slot.html
- http://www.aliexpress.com/popular/3g-sd-card-modem.html
- http://dx.com/en/p/7-2m-hsdpa-3g-usb-2-0-wireless-modem-adapter-with-tf-card-slot-black-47013#.UwzU8x_F8Vk

Comment: So I can boot from these devices into Linux Live_USB style, and use the 3g or 4g connection from the device at the same time?

Comment: I don't see why not. It would be very strange if the device was created to only allow you to use either the storage or the modem one at a time, that would mean that as long as your Internet connection is active you cannot access the SD card. Of course this would depend on the specific device so it's impossible to answer, but it sounds unreasonable.